# Pytorch: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) face recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am doing evaluation on seven datasets with pretrianed model.The all datasets are in same folder with their `.bin`,and`.npy` files. I tried a lot to fix the error but still i am unable to do so. When i was doing training it works very well.

**Original Code** `https://github.com/zhongyy/Face-Transformer/blob/main/test_forward.py`

Repo:https://github.com/zhongyy/Face-Transformer

**Code**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import sys
from vit_pytorch import ViT_face
from util.utils import get_val_data, perform_val, perform_val_deit, buffer_val, test_forward
from IPython import embed
import sklearn
import cv2
import numpy as np
from image_iter import FaceDataset
import torch.utils.data as data
import argparse
import os


DEVICE = torch.device("cuda:0")
DATA_ROOT = '/home/cvpr/Documents/ms1m-retinaface-t1/'
with open(os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'property'), 'r') as f:
    NUM_CLASS, h, w = [int(i) for i in f.read().split(',')]

model = ViT_face(
    image_size=112,
    patch_size=8,
    loss_type='CosFace',
    GPU_ID=DEVICE,
    num_class=NUM_CLASS,
    dim=512,
    depth=20,
    heads=8,
    mlp_dim=2048,
    dropout=0.1,
    emb_dropout=0.1
)

model_root = '/home/cvpr/Documents/Backbone_VIT_Epoch_2_Batch_20000_Time_2021-01-12-16-48_checkpoint.pth'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_root))

TARGET = 'lfw'
vers = get_val_data('/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval')
print(vers)
for ver in vers:
    name, data_set, issame = ver
    time = test_forward(DEVICE, model, data_set)
    print(time)
```

**print(vers)**

```
(carray((12000, 3, 112, 112), float32)
  nbytes := 1.68 GB; cbytes := 9.02 MB; ratio: 190.96
  cparams := cparams(clevel=5, shuffle=1, cname='lz4', quantize=0)
  chunklen := 13; chunksize: 1956864; blocksize: 262144
  rootdir := '/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval/lfw'
  mode    := 'r'
[[[[ 0.92941177  0.94509804  0.96862745 ..., -0.81960785 -0.7647059
    -0.73333335]
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/test_forward.py", line 42, in <module>
    name, data_set, issame = ver
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Comment: get_val_data returns less than 3 variables, as the error says. can't know more without you posting its code.

Comment: @Gulzar I have posted the repo link, when i was doing training the get_val_data works fine but on testing it makes problem.

Comment: I am not going in the link. Make the question self contained and show what you have tried. The error is crystal clear - you are trying to put less than 3 values into 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

simple example of the error mean:
you have sequence/iterable variable (list, dict, etc):
example:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then you unpack the list:

correct:

```
a, b, c, d = my_list
```

wrong with error : ValueError: too many values to unpack

```
x, y = my_list
```

in your case, you unpack this :
you unpack variable ver, wich is not more than 3 values within

Comment: Do you any suggestion how to solve this? Actually, I tried it but it didn't work